# How can I make annotations more semantic?

Tags: java, annotations

I am writing a library, so I don't often use the methods in my classes within the same project. As such, my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) keeps warning me that the methods are unused.

Of course, the obvious solution is to place `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` before the classes. I don't like this; it doesn't describe the reason I'm writing that annotation and is very verbose. I would love to make an annotation like `@LibraryClass` which is just an alias of `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`.

In short, **I want to be able to change this:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MyLibraryClass {
  public void myLibraryMethod() {
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

**to this:**

```
@LibraryClass
public class MyLibraryClass {
  public void myLibraryMethod() {
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

but I have no idea how to do this! I tried all this, and it compiles, but the IDE still warns of unused methods:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, CONSTRUCTOR, LOCAL_VARIABLE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Library {
    SuppressWarnings superAnnotation() default @SuppressWarnings("unused");

    String[] value() default {"unused"};
}
```

Comment: That warning doesn't appear if there are tests which call the methods.

Comment: @sisyphus good point! I'll add that to my to-do list. Still, I'd love to know how to make semantic annotations.

Answer (score 1):

To do one aspect of what you're asking for - attaching some kind of compile-time logic to annotations - you need to look into annotation processing. An annotation processor hooks into the Java runtime, like an agent, and gets informed about annotations and given an option to process it. To use that, you'd have to put your annotation-processor jar on the IDE's classpath.

Some links:

http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101
http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/playing-with-java-annotation-processing.html

However, that wouldn't allow you to *change* the way that Intellij detects unused methods, which seems to be closer to your specific use case. What you could do there is to modify the Intellij 'unused method' inspection so that it incorporates a check for the custom annotation you've defined. YMMV, I've never had to do that at the class level before.

https://gist.github.com/itzg/5e90609cde1473ef9d4d